# Parsing large XML files into PowerShell objects

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing

I'm a PowerShell and XPath beginner struggling to efficiently parse through some XML and build up an array of objects for further processing (e.g. CSV output, SQL Server load). A sample of the XML is included below as well as the code snippet that I'm currently using. In this schema, each `object-array` represents a single row in the desired output. I'm parsing the `MetaData` children to get the proper names of the columns, then building a collection of PSObjects where each object in the array represents a single row. The `MetaData` information is used to find the column names (PSObject properties).

This works fine for files with 10K rows or so, but bogs down horribly when run against my largest files with over 500K rows. In these cases each row is taking around 3-4 seconds to process. At 500K rows, that's a looong time to run. Is there some magic around XPath or PS variable assignment that I can use to speed this up?

The immediate need to is translate this XML into a CSV (currently performed via `export-csv`), but I'd prefer to have this portion of the script generate a collection of objects as I'll next be looking to either load this data into a SQL Server instance or do other processing.

Thanks for the help!

David

## Sample XML

```
<Report>
<Data>
<Columns>
<MetaData>
<Index>0</Index>
<Name>Column1</Name>
<Index>1</Index>
<Name>Column2</Name>
<Index>2</Index>
<Name>Column3</Name>
</MetaData>
</Columns>
<Rows>
<object-array>
<string>column1 value</string>
<int>column2 value</string>
<string>column3 value</string>
</object-array>
</Rows>
</Data>
</Report>
```

## Sample Code

```
#extract the column headers
[string[]]$ColumnHeaders = @()
$obj.SelectNodes("/Report/Data/Columns/MetaData") |% {$ColumnHeaders += $_.name}

$collection = @()
$rowint = 0
$rowcount = $obj.Report.Data.Rows."object-array".count

#unwind the rows
do {
    $hash=@{}

    #loop through each element in the row parent element and add it to the hash
    $columnint = 0
    $columncount = (Select-Xml -xPath "Report/Data/Rows/object-array[$rowint]/node()" $obj).count
        do {
            $hash.Add($columnheaders[$columnint], (Select-Xml -xPath "Report/Data/Rows/object-array[$rowint]/descendant::text()[$columnint]" $obj).Node.Value)
            $columnint++
        } while ($columnint -lt $columncount)


    $thisrow = New-Object PSObject -Property $hash 

    #add this new row to the collection 
    $collection += $thisrow 
    $rowint++
} while ($rowint -lt $rowcount)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get MetaData names without re-creating ColumnHeaders in each itreation:

```
$ColumnHeaders = $obj.Report.Data.Columns.MetaData.Name
```

Same applies to $collection. How the end result of your code looks like?

UPDATE: Give this a try

```
[xml]$obj = Get-Content test.xml

$data = $obj.Report.Data

$pso = New-Object PSObject
$pso | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name $data.Columns.MetaData.Name[0] -Value $data.Rows.'object-array'.string[0]
$pso | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name $data.Columns.MetaData.Name[1] -Value $data.Rows.'object-array'.int
$pso | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name $data.Columns.MetaData.Name[2] -Value $data.Rows.'object-array'.string[1] -PassThru
```

Comment: `$obj.Report.Data.Columns.MetaData.Name` returns nothing, while `$obj.Report.Data.Columns.MetaData |gm` shows I'm getting back XMLElements, which have the Name property associated. The end result is an array `$collection` of objects that can then be piped to export-csv, ft, or other PS processing.

Comment: Can you include a sample output?

Comment: The output is a collection of PSObjects, having properties that correspond to the column headers and values that correspond to the row (object-array). In the sample XML, the result would be a single object with the following property/value pairs: Column1="Column1 Value", Column2="Column2 Value", Column3="Column3 Value". In the case of processing live data, there would be a PS array of between 10,000-500,000 of these objects, which could then be pipped to export-csv, a dataset for SQL Server loading, or processed further straight in PS.

Comment: To clarify, each `<object-array>` group is the equivalent of a row in a spreadsheet. I'm trying to parse the MetaData group to get the proper column headings (only happens once at the start of the script) and then populate all the rows (PSObjects) with the data found in all of the `object-array` elements, of which there are several thousand object-array elements in a given XML file.

Comment: Updated my answer, give it a try

Comment: Is there a way to take that approach without hard coding the order of the values (string, followed by int, followed by string)? The advantage of the current method is that the data types in the object-array can be in any order/combination. With your suggested code, only one type of report (string, followed by int, followed by string) can be parsed. I'll try hard coding for the large report type and verify if the performance is better.

Comment: Do you have any other information you can base the creation of objects on?

Comment: Not really. This code segment is taking the result of a REST query to a report engine that generates XML in a generic format that is flexible for all the various different report types that it can generate. The MetaData stanza describes the order, column names, and data type to be found in the object-array (row) stanzas. Is select-xml known to be much slower than the PS direct object reference method? I've yet to come across any information that gives performance guidance for working with the various ways of querying XML in PS. It's the lack of knowing that's most frustrating.